# R: sum the elements of each list on a list and return the result in a data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested-lists

I have a list of lists in R; each list has the results of a Grep command indicating the position where the search string was found. The command

```
> matches<-lapply(ListOfFiles, function(x)
+ grep("SearchString",readLines(x),ignore.case = T))
```

produces

```
//I copy the results that the function actually yields for the sake of the example

> matches<-list(c(11L, 13L), c(9L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 25L
+ ), c(5L, 8L, 11L), c(10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 16L), c(5L, 7L, 9L), 
+ integer(0))

> matches
[[1]]
[1] 11 13

[[2]]
[1]  9 12 14 15 16 19 20 22 25

[[3]]
[1]  5  8 11

[[4]]
[1] 10 11 13 14 16

[[5]]
[1] 5 7 9

[[6]]
integer(0)
```

I need to transform this to a simple data frame of 6 rows and 1 column, with each "cell" having the sum of each of the 6 lists of `matches`.

If at all possible, please try to explain the syntax I should employ; I'm new to R and sometimes I find examples difficult to follow if several things are nested at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually just figured it out on my own. The answer is:

```
data.frame(unlist(lapply(matches, function(x) sum(x))))
```

the first part yiels a list of lists with one element each, the summation of the elements of each list

```
> lapply(matches, function(x) sum(x))
[[1]]
[1] 24

[[2]]
[1] 152

[[3]]
[1] 24

[[4]]
[1] 64

[[5]]
[1] 21

[[6]]
[1] 0
```

the second part generates a vector from that. Evidently it is a recursive function:

```
> unlist(lapply(matches, function(x) sum(x)))
[1]  24 152  24  64  21   0
```

Finally it is transformed into a dataframe using the `data.frame()` function.

Comment: Simpler still: `sapply(matches, sum)`

Comment: Since you only have on argument to `x` you can just do: `data.frame(sapply(matches, sum))`

Comment: O_O Thanks to you both!! Yesterday I spent so much time with this and now I just saw it. Still, thanks for pointing me to `sapply`, really useful.

Comment: @josilber, but `sapply` is likely to be slower than `unlist(lapply(matches, sum))`. Better than `sapply` would be `vapply(matches, sum, numeric(1L))`.

Comment: In which order would it be relevant, 100,000 records? More? Less? (Just for curiosity; in my application I'm grepping 100MB worth of .txt files and that will dwarf any other inefficiency in the code.)

Comment: @AnandaMahto true, though for most lists the time needed to type the extra characters in your expressions far exceeds the runtime advantages =)

Comment: @josilber, then try `rapply(matches, sum)` :-)

Comment: Aren't rapply and sapply the same in this case?

Comment: @AnandaMahto on my benchmark I just pulled together (100000 list elements of sizes 1-10) `rapply` is no faster than `sapply`, and `vapply` and `unlist`+`lapply` are 3.5x faster (6.5 microseconds vs. 21 microseconds).

Comment: @josilber, the comment wasn't meant to be taken too seriously! s_a, any of these would make sense for a problem like this. The code for `sapply` checks at the end to see whether the results can be simplified. With `vapply` you specify the output template so the function is a little bit faster.

Comment: @josilber, Hmmm. Woke up to this again--[`rapply` performs closer to `vapply` for me](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/3c09f9419cd2b78eb19c).

Comment: @s_a, you can go ahead and accept your answer. I don't think you're going to get anything better! :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto interesting -- I saw a lot more different between the four approaches in my benchmarking (comment added in your link).

Comment: @josilber, other than you having a much faster system than me, I'm not sure what to make of this. I just added a comment with my timings on your sample data.